# Monkey patching in django settings

Tags: python, django, mocking, settings

I'm trying to do something that should be simple, which is to test Django settings given different OS environment set.

I'm using the Mock library from http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/

And the code is very simple

```
@patch('os')
def test_reading_backends_as_list(self, os):
    os.environ = {'VAR': 'VALUE'}
    import settings
    self.assertEqual(settings.VAR, 'VALUE')
```

that doesn't work however, because in the settings module the os is actually never patched!

I think the reason is related to the fact that settings is used to run the tests, which means that is loaded already.

However I also tried to do

```
del settings
import settings
```

or reload it, but nothing, still the same.
Also doing @patch('settings.os') fails.

Anyone managed to do that?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of settings would you have that would be different on different systems?

Comment: That't not the problem, the problem is simply testing some (light) logic in the settings, that parse environment variables and do something with it.

So far I haven't found a way to do it, one ex colleague of mine did something manipulating the text itself and using eval,which I would like to avoid.